# How can I pass an SVG and some markup as a React prop?

Tags: reactjs, svg, react-props

I have a React button component that accepts a `text` prop, which is used to set the text of the button.

`<Button text="My Button Text" />`

This works well, but I want to set the text as an SVG with some markup. If I pass just the SVG, that works.

```
import { ReactComponent as IconSearch } from '../../icons/search.svg';

<Button text={<IconSearch />} />
```

Once, I add the markup though, it stops working.

```
import { ReactComponent as IconSearch } from '../../icons/search.svg';

<Button text={`${<IconSearch />} <span>Search</span>`} />
```

How can I pass an SVG and some markup as the prop?

Comment: Did you make it? I am looking for something similar to your question

Answer (score 1):

Wrap both elements as a separate Component :

```
const ButtonContent = () => 
    <>
        <IconSearch />
        <span>Search</span>
    </>

<Button text={<ButtonContent />} />
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the current attempt is it passes a string, which resembles JSX, like:

```
"<IconSearch /> <span>Search</span>"
```

In order to pass a combo of SVG with text, we'll need to wrap them into their own component, and pass this new component to the Button component. Here's a working example:

```js
const SVG = () => (
  <svg height="100" width="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" /> 
  </svg> 
)

const SVGwithText = () => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <SVG />
    <span>Search</span>
  </React.Fragment>
)

const Button = ({text}) => (
  <button>{text}</button>
)

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Button text="Button Text" />
    <Button text={<SVGwithText />} />
  </div>
)

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

If it's possible to change the Button component to use `children` that would be another option. In that setup you would be able to do the following:

```
<Button>
  <SVG />
  <span>Search</span>
</Button>
```

Here's a working example of that setup:

```js
const SVG = () => (
  <svg height="100" width="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" /> 
  </svg> 
)

const Button = ({children}) => (
  <button>{children}</button>
)

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Button>
      Button Text
    </Button>
    <Button>
      <SVG />
      <span>Search</span>
    </Button>
  </div>
)

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```